# htaccess redirect ugly multi lang url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, multilingual

I am trying to change my ugly urls from this:

```
domain.com/page.php?lang=en
domain.com/page.php?lang=al
```

into this:

```
domain.com/page.php (when it's english)
domain.com/al/page.php (when it's albanian)
```

I have tried many answers from other stackoverflow solutions but none worked for me.

Anyone can help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For `domain.com/page.php?lang=en` use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /page.php?lang=en [L]
```

For `domain.com/page.php?lang=al` use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^al/page\.php$ /page.php?lang=al [L]
```

Comment: I have 7-8 pages. Is there a way to make the code for all pages? And not all one by one.

Comment: Depends on how you want the layouts done. Obviously the layouts on those two URLs are different, therefore it required for me to do different code for them. However, if you want the designs the same as those, then both of those will work for multiple urls.